# DialogFlow - Calling an intent on button click

Tags: dialogflow-es, custom-events, google-console-developer

1. I am trying to build a web application(MVC .net core)
2. I just create a simple html button and it hits on the post method of HomeController, starttalking().
3. All I need to do is as soon as this button is clicked, the google home speaks up the welcome intent response without any input phrase.

Can someone guide me in identifying how can I invoke a dialog flow's intent on the click of a button in .net. I mean i Know i can set intents and their fullfilment webhooks but this scenario first button gets click then response of the intent should be triggered. Is it even possible? I had been going through the custom events and felt it can somehow accomplish my goal but im clueless how to do it. Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Triggering a response on a Google Home device from a different device isn't possible.

You could look into triggering a [notification](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications), however notifications on the Assistant currently only get sent to mobile devices, not devices such as the Google Home. Even if it did, however, it would still require the user to acknowledge the response before the conversation continued.

You could also look into continuing the conversation with the Assistant through the web page or web app itself using the [Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/). This would be similar to embedding a Google Home inside your app.